# ink-file-picker filepicker.io confirmation message upon upload

Tags: filepicker.io

I am using Ink Filepicker to get uploaded files from visitors to my site.
It us uploading to my Amazon S3 - that's all fine.

Some users aren't sure that their files are being uploaded though ,so they are doing it multiple times and/or emailing in the file anyway.

Is there a simple way to get a confirmation message to display when the file is uploaded (like a popup message box)?

Thanks for any help you can offer

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onSuccess callback function. This function will fire when the upload has been completed successfully. Here is a very basic example...

```
filepicker.pickAndStore({
        mimetypes: 'image/*',
        services: ['computer','url']
    },
    // onSuccess callback
    function(data) {
        $('body').append('<div class="modal">UPLOAD COMPLETE!</div>');
    }
);
```